# What are the most common tourist scams in Germany, specifically in Munich and Berlin?

Tags: germany, berlin, munich, scams, tourist-traps

I've been to a few Asian and Europian countries which were filled with lots of tourist scams/traps; from sim card, taxi, coffee, to [string people](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13300/whats-the-deal-with-the-string-people-in-central-paris) and even [fake police officers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55858/is-it-possible-to-insist-on-having-your-id-checked-at-the-police-station-not-in/55865#55865).

I wonder, is this also true for Germany? More specifically in Munich and Berlin.

Comment: Not anything particular about Germany but don't ever give money to beggars.

Comment: Scams are everywhere so there's nothing special about Germany.  Fake police officers are probably much less likely in the West but all the normal cautions apply.

Comment: If there's any particularly common scam, then it should be mentioned in the "stay safe" section of a travel guide.

Comment: In Berlin we have a lot of the deaf people collecting signatures on some petition, and if you yell at them they understand you quite well and run away. The police by now has put up signs for that. I've not seen that in Munich though. There are a lot less international tourists in Munich. You should be fine.